# Confusion with how JS engine runs promises?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and was learning promises. So, let's say we have this code:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 1000); // (*)

}).then(function(result) { // (**)

  alert(result); // 1
  return result * 2;

})
```

As you can see the code above, when promise is invoked, setTimeout is run via callback queue. The question is When setTimeOut is sent to a browser, will JS engine omit .then() and continues running the rest of the code until the promise resolves? Secondly, async/await example:

```
async function showAvatar() {

  // read our JSON
  let response = await fetch('/article/promise-chaining/user.json');
  let user = await response.json();

  // read github user
  let githubResponse = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user.name}`);
  let githubUser = await githubResponse.json();

  // show the avatar
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = githubUser.avatar_url;
  img.className = "promise-avatar-example";
  document.body.append(img);

  // wait 3 seconds
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));

  img.remove();

  return githubUser;
}

showAvatar();
```

When showAvatar function is called, JS engine will encounter `let response = await fetch('/article/promise-chaining/user.json');` and sends fetch to the browser to handle. The second question is Will JS engine wait until fetch gets resolved or Will JS engine continue executing  `let user = await response.json();` and the rest of the code inside showAvatar function? If so, how can JS engine handle response.json() since response is not received? Hope you got my point))).

Comment: In your first example, the promise is resolved when the timer ends, so the browser waits for the duration of the timer, which resolves the promise, before it can execute the callback in `.then()`. In your second question, as the name `await` suggests, it will pause execution of the code until the promise that is being awaited for is resolved. As the browser waits for `user.json` to respond, the next line will not be executed until the response is received.

Comment: @Terry, hi, thanks for your kind comments, in the first example, if JS engine waits until promise is resolved before running then(), I think it will block the interaction. Concerning the second example, ok if await makes the function stop, is it true that by using async we push showAvatar function aside from the call stack so that it does not block the main stack?

Comment: @MII - Neither of them blocks the main JavaScript thread waiting for the promise to settle. Once the engine has hooked up the `then` handler it goes on to do other things until the timer fires. The `async` function is suspended at each `await`, allowing the thread to do other things, and resumed when the promise being awaited settles.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, concerning async/await example, when async function is suspended at each await, will async function is removed from the call stack and is put back to the call stack again when the promise being awaited settles?

Comment: @MII - I've added an answer to that to my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example works like this:

1. `new Promise` runs, calling the function you pass it (the *executor function*) synchronously
2. Code in the executor function calls `setTimeout`, passing in a function to call 1000ms later; the browser adds that to its list of pending timer callbacks
3. `new Promise` returns the promise
4. `then` is called, adding the function you pass into it to the promise's list of fulfillment handlers and creating a new promise (which your code doesn't use, so it gets thrown away).
5. 1000ms or so later, the browser queues a call to the `setTimeout` callback, which the JavaScript engine picks up and runs
6. The callback calls the `resolve` function to fulfill the promise with the value 1
7. That triggers the promise's fulfillment handlers (asynchronously, but it doesn't really matter for this example), so the handler attached in Step 4 gets called, showing the `alert` and then returning `result * 2` (which is `1 * 2`, which is `1`). That value is used to fulfill the promise created and thrown away in Step 4.

> Will JS engine wait until fetch gets resolved or Will JS engine continue executing `let user = await response.json();`...

It waits. The `async` function is suspended at the `await` in `await fetch(/*...*/)`, waiting for the promise `fetch` returned to settle. While it's suspended, the main JavaScript thread can do other things. Later, when the promise settles, the function is resumed and either the fulfillment value is assigned to `response` (if the promise is fulfilled) or an exception will get thrown (if it is rejected).

More generally: `async` functions are synchronous up until the first `await` or `return` in their code. At that point, they return their promise, which is settled later based on the remainder of the `async` function's code.

---

In a comment you asked:

> when async function is suspended at each await, will async function is removed from the call stack and is put back to the call stack again when the promise being awaited settles?

At a low level, yes; but to make debugging easier, a good, up-to-date JavaScript engine maintains an "async call stack" they use for error traces and such. For instance, if you run this on Chrome...

```js
function delay(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function inner() {
    await delay(80);
    throw new Error("boom");
}

async function outer() {
    await inner();
}

function wrapper() {
    outer()
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.stack);
    });
}

wrapper();
```

...the stack looks like this:

```
Error: boom
    at inner (https://stacksnippets.net/js:18:11)
    at async outer (https://stacksnippets.net/js:22:5)
```

Notice the "async" prior to "outer," and also notice that `wrapper` isn't mentioned anywhere. `wrapper` is done and has returned, but the `async` functions were suspended and resumed.

Comment: FWIW, I go into promises and `async` functions in some depth in Chapters 8 and 9 of my new book, see my profile for links.